# Regular expression to separate out the last occurring number using Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a regular expression which separates out the number from the given string.

```
username = "testuser1"
xp = r'^\D+'
ma = re.match(xp, username)
user_prefix = ma.group(0)
print user_prefix
```

output is

```
testuser
```

But if the username is something like below

```
username = "testuser1-1"
```

I am getting the following output

```
testuser
```

which is expected. But I am looking for the following

```
testuser1-
```

Basically the regular expression should separate out the last occurring whole number (not individual digits).

Summary is

```
input = "testuser1"
>>> output = testuser
input = "testuser1-1"
>>> output = testuser1-
input = "testuser1-2000"
>>> output = testuser1-
```

Can I have a single regular expression to deal with the above all cases..?

Comment: Hi Hearner, I have added third case as well for better understanding. Please have a look.

Comment: @Hearner I think he wants to delete the last char if it is a digit.

Comment: You can also match until last non-digit: [`^.*(?<!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/pE1qS2/1) by use of lookebhind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` and look behind syntax:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\D)\d+$', '', username)
```

A shorter version:

```
re.sub(r'\d+$', '', username)
```

The `sub` function is more suited for this case.

Test cases:

```
re.sub(r'\d+$', '', "testuser1-100")
# 'testuser1-'

re.sub(r'\d+$', '', "testuser1-1")
# 'testuser1-'

re.sub(r'\d+$', '', "testuser1")
# 'testuser'
```

Comment: You don't need the look-behind part. `\d+$` is enough.

Comment: @melpomene Well. Seems like I always prefer to make things more complicated than it needs to be :)

Answer (score 5):

A solution using re.match:

```
import re
username = "testuser1"
xp = r'^(.+?)\d+$'
ma = re.match(xp, username)
user_prefix = ma.groups()[0]
user_prefix
# 'testuser'

# you can also capture the last number
xp = r'^(.+?)(\d+)$'
ma = re.match(xp, username)
user_prefix, user_number = ma.groups()
user_prefix, user_number
# ('testuser', '1')

print re.match(xp, "testuser1-2000").groups()
# ('testuser1-', '2000')
re.match(xp, "testuser1-2000").groups()[0]
# 'testuser1-'
re.match(xp, "testuser1-2000").group(1)
# 'testuser1-'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here!

```
regex_ = '\w+-?(?:\d+)?'
```

Comment: This seems like an unnecessary complication for a simple problem.

Comment: Right! But that's what OP wants!

Comment: This will fail for strings like `testuser-1-11111-2222`

Comment: It  will even fail for test+user-12, look at the Domain of the problem by the OP

Comment: What do you mean by `(? :\d+)`?

Comment: Sorry there is no whitespace between `? ` and  `:` -  (keyboard auto space) anyways edited the answer ,  it means a non capturing version of a group https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: Yet this regex matches whole `testuser1-2000` and not `testuser1-` only.

Answer (score 1):

Less engine involving regex (considering `-` as the only token)

```
^([^\s-]+-|\D+)
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest starting from the end, deleting each char and stopping at the first non-number.

Comment: @Caridoc, thanks for the answer. But it won't work for the third case. If user is testuser1-2000, it returns testuser1-200, but I am looking for testuser1-

Comment: @user3157132 ok, I though you were intersted in a single final number

Comment: @user3157132 I devised an alternative method for your new requirements and it works but it looks harder then regex now.